# What's wrong with this MySQL connection?

Tags: php, mysql

I have setup a MySQL database and I am trying to connect to it from another website.

I get this error when I try to connect to it:
Connection failed: Access denied for user 'myUsername'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

It works fine when I do it in the same website where the database is hosted.
I tried this SQL query:

```
GRANT SELECT, DELETE, UPDATE ON database.myDatabaseName TO 'myUsername'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'myPassword';
```

But I got this error:

```
#1142 - SELECT,UPDATE,DE command denied to user 'Steve'@'localhost' for table 'myDatabaseName'
```

I went to the MySQL management in the built-in control panel where I modified permissions of Steve and added the Grant permission, however I still get the same #1142 error.

How can I fix this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check if the database can accesed by this user from everywhere or only from localhost (there's a setting in the user called Host). Seems to me that it's set to localhost.

Comment: `myUsername` vs. `Steve`. Is that a typo?

Comment: `Access denied for user 'myUsername'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` Steve or MyUsername ?

Comment: Sorry about that, it's myUsername.

Comment: It's still not working though.

Answer (score 2):

```
Access denied for user 'myUsername'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

That's where the error is. It says you are attempting to connect to localhost with the username `myUsername` and a supplied password. However, usually on localhost, especially on windows systems, the user is `Root` and the password is not set, just an empty string. Check your username on your localhost and your password.

Comment: I tried to put root for username and empty string for password but I got this: Connection failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)